# Australian rocket launches

Tags: launch-site

Is there a rocket launching facility in Western Victoria or Eastern South Australia, situated west of Warracknabeal in Victoria?
I witnessed what appeared to be two stage launch whilst travelling North from Warracknabeal in late April 2016.  Can find no data anywhere.

Comment: There's the [RAAF Woomera Range Complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAAF_Woomera_Range_Complex) in South Australia. Couldn't find informations about rocket launches with a quick search, though it seems that they still do launch small rockets.

Comment: ESA, in the earlier days, wanted to use a existing rocket launch site in Australia instead of building their own. But I think it plan didn't go trough because of lack of commitment of Australian government. Nevertheless there definitely are launch site in Australia, the question is how active they are. The closest active site I can think of is the on of RocketLabs in east NZ.

Comment: historical reference to Australian launches: [Did the British Skylark ever launch from the UK?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23695/12102) and also [landing(s)](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/30304/12102)