# How large an asteroid sample does hayabusa2 have?

Tags: sample-return, hayabusa2

As the title says, is it known how big, or massive, hayabusa2's sample is, due for Earth touchdown on 6th December?

I have tried some basic internet research but found nothing on the anticipated sample size.

Edit: Evidence that nobody knows yet would also be an acceptable answer.

Comment: Different spacecraft and mission, but interesting comparison: [Actual mass of Hayabusa samples in 2010?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30303/12102)

Comment: @uhoh - I'm certainly hoping they get more than they did with Hayabusa.

Answer (score 3):

A total of 5.424 ± 0.217 g was collected from Ryugu
https://www.nature.com/articles/s41550-021-01550-6