# Actual mass of Hayabusa 2 samples in 2020?

Tags: sample-return, hayabusa2

*Similar to [Actual mass of Hayabusa samples in 2010?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/30303/actual-mass-of-hayabusa-samples-in-2010), but about the recent mission.*

What is the actual mass of the samples retrieved by [Hayabusa 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayabusa2)?

The most detailed information I was able to find is:

[Hayabusa2 delivers asteroid samples to Earth after six-year voyage](https://spacenews.com/hayabusa2-delivers-asteroid-samples-to-earth-after-six-year-voyage/):

> A five-gram tantalum projectile was fired down the horn with a sample of material being delivered up the instrument, collecting a planned total sample mass of over 100 milligrams. The second sampling excavated pristine material from beneath the surface, where it would have been shielded from space weathering. The spacecraft departed for Earth in November 2019

Is seems there actually two samples, the first one over 100 mg, the mass of the second one is not speficied.

Answer (score 3):

According to [an article on CNet](https://www.cnet.com/news/hayabusa2s-asteroid-sample-treasure-box-has-been-opened-for-the-first-time/), regarding the subsurface collection in chamber C:

> JAXA will open chamber C in the coming days and then start to assess the recovered samples using an optical microscope and observing the spectra in infrared. ... Collaborating with international space agencies will maximize the science output from the sample, which **JAXA estimates to be around 1 to 2 grams.**

Comment: A nice image to put things into perspective https://twitter.com/haya2e_jaxa/status/1338754705644634112

Answer (score 0):

According to [The Japan Times article](https://www.japantimes.co.jp/news/2020/12/19/national/science-health/hayabusa2-asteroid-soil/), the sample mass after recovery was more than 5.4 grams.

> The capsule brought back by the Hayabusa2 space probe contained more than 5.4 grams of soil samples from a distant asteroid, exceeding the original target of 0.1 gram, Japan’s space agency has said.